# Windows 7: Could not find gem 'typhoeus (~> 0.8.0) x64-mingw32'

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Unable to start rails server in Windows 7

```
Could not find gem '`typhoeus (~> 0.8.0) x64-mingw32`' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine. Run bundle install to install missing gems.
```

Any help would be appreciated !!!